# dividing a square into unique rectangles with the same perimeter

Tags: co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, tiling

There's a solution for dividing a square into unique rectangles with the same area which is the blanche dissection. 
There's also a solution for dividing a square into unique rectangles with the same diagonal by Ed Pegg.
In addition theres even a solution for dividing a square into similar rectangles where the solution even uses the plastic constant as a part of the solution. 
But what about a solution for dividing a square into unique rectangles with the same perimeter?

Comment: The area problem is discussed at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220567/tiling-a-square-with-rectangles

Comment: This question was touched upon in this 2013 document: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1307/1307.3472.pdf and a guess was made that the answer is negative (page 5). A "rectangle" that can be cut into 7 rectangles all of same perimeter but different areas is shown. A further question as to whether there are rectangles that can be cut into more than 9 rectangles all of same perimeter and different areas is also posed.